# "ParseRequestException: your Mongo database is unavailable" while logging with Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, mongodb, parse-platform

I have worked on an Android app where I have used Parse as my backend. It was working good earlier but now suddenly, I am getting **"ParseRequestException: your Mongo database is unavailable"** when logging with Facebook.

I know I need to migrate it to somewhere other third party backend. But can anyone tell me the reason for the issue?

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: This exception is not related to facebook. can you please try to sign up or login the user with email and password or to execute any other query to parse and check if you get the same error? i think that parse server not "see" your mongo DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My database was shifted to Amazon AWS and there is some setting to be made with Facebook console details. Once I have done the setting, it started to work properly.